# Deleted boot sector

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8.1, boot-partition

I decided to delete my boot sector in GParted to stop the Windows partition on my HDD from booting (I have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1). I am now only able to access the BIOS and a few other basic utilities, and have determined that the Hard Drive has no other issues. How do I restore functionality to my computer?

Comment: Try BootRepair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Boot from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB you created, and boot into the live desktop.
2. Open terminal
3. Connect to a network with internet access
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   boot-repair
   ```
5. Click the `Recommended Repair` option
6. When the repair is finished, note the `paste.ubuntu.com` URL
7. Reboot and check if the repair was successful.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair